# React app does not render inside Facebook instant game iframe

Tags: reactjs, facebook-instant-games

I have a react app which does not render when zipped and loaded into facebook instant game platform. It generates logs such as below, that clearly show that the actions are firing. See the logs with `Middleware ACTION-NAME` below.

If someone can give me ideas on what could be going wrong, that would be great. Does JSX in an iframe need some special permissions to write to the #root tag?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it thus,

I am using BrowserRouter in react for navigation. I had to change the route path I wanted to load initially from / to * .

```
-                <Route exact path="/">
+                <Route exact path="*">
```

It seems like initially, when running the game inside the iframe, the route path did not match `/` .